# idiom for proceeding slowly and with difficulty

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrase-requests

Is there an idiom I could use if I wanted to say that
someone is doing something with a lot difficulty and slowly?

I cannot think of anything.
Thanks

*Edit from comment:*

For example: You have learnt a lot of things and you will sail through the exams. Your lazy friends on the contrary will ***slog*** their way through it.

Is there an expression I can use instead of *slog* to convey a similar meaning?

Comment: You can say he is "finding the work challenging".

Comment: How about `clamber`?

Comment: Thanks Dan Bron but I would like something like an idiom.

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of thing they might be doing and/or the circumstances where you would make your comment?  Something like "He's slogging his way through it" , or "it's a real slog" might work.  (see [slog](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slog) at m-w.com)

Comment: #Area 51 Detective Fiction can it be used in a sentence without the meaning "to climb"? If yes, could you give me an example?

Comment: #Hellion I would say: "You have learnt a lot of things and you will sail through the exams. Your lazy friends on the contrary will slog their way though it". Can I use your expression in this case?

Comment: "Grinding away at" it?

Comment: *Slog through something* is an idiom already. Another similar one is *plow through something*.

Comment: 'trudge' is a bit more idiomatic since it usually refers to walking with difficulty, but can be used like 'we slowly trudged through the job'.

Comment: LUMBER intransitive verb  1  :  to move ponderously (Merriam Webster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wading through treacle** gets several hits on line

If the effort is doomed to failure it can be described as a Sisyphean task

>

> Merriam Webster 
>   Definition of SISYPHEAN :  of, relating to, or suggestive of the
>   labors of Sisyphus
>
> SISYPHUS :  a legendary king of Corinth condemned eternally to
>   repeatedly roll a heavy rock up a hill in Hades only to have it roll
>   down again as it nears the top

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is "swimming through porridge"

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, ***flounder/wade through (something)***

> flounder through
>
> *Fig.* to struggle awkwardly through a difficult situation.
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/flounder+through)
>
> *I floundered through the test because I never studied*.
>
> [Quizlet](https://quizlet.com/120148275/vocab-unit-9-flash-cards/)

Answer (score 0):

drudging through the work? that's properly idiomatic but it sounds kind of demeaning, as in speaking assertively, rather than in terms intended to teach as idioms do. But this phrasing certainly fits the definition as dictionary.com defines it.